# Api platform Custom Exception with translator message

Tags: api, symfony, validation, api-platform.com

I am using custom endpoint with custom controller in api platfrom for user instance.

```
class PayingMembershipForOthersController
{

    private ValidatorInterface $validator;

    public function __construct(ValidatorInterface $validator)
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    public function __invoke(User $data)
    {
        $this->validator->validate($data);
        try {
           $paymentService->paymentMembership($data);
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
           throw $e
        }
        return $data;
    }

}
```

if user is not found my $userService throw custom exception like below.

```
class XXXException extends \Exception
{
    public function __construct(
        $message = "user.notfound.message",  // Translation file key.
        $code = 0,
        Throwable $previous = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
    }
}
```

So here i want send translation message ( UserNotFound [de_DE] and UserNotFound [en_EN]. so can you please help me here.

Thanks in advance..!!!

Comment: Do these exceptions are catched or converted to `Response` when thrown ?

Comment: Can you guide me how can we achieve this  "exceptions are cached or converted to Response when thrown" ?

Comment: Exceptions appear to get normalized by <service id="api_platform.hydra.normalizer.error" class="ApiPlatform\Core\Hydra\Serializer\ErrorNormalizer" public="false">. Maybe you can replace this service by an instance of a subclass that overrides ::getErrorMessage by an implementation that does translation? That way the errors on the log will be untranslated, which may be less explanatory but much easyer for searching the log.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is two useful tools with API-Platform to handle `Exception`:

1. [exception to HTTP status](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/errors/#converting-php-exceptions-to-http-errors),
2. [exception event subscriber](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/events/#the-event-system).

The first one allow you to throw an exception from anywhere of your code. API-Platform will catch it, then convert it to a beautiful `Response`:

```yaml
# config/packages/api_platform.yaml

api_platform:
    # ...
    exception_to_status:
        App\Exception\MyException: 400
        App\Exception\AnotherException: 500
```

The next one allow to catch a thrown exception and to deal with it. In your case, the payload is to translate the exception message to the appropriate language. In this example, I use [Symfony translator service](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html):

```php
namespace App\EventSubscriber;


use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

class ExceptionSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private TranslatorInterface $translator;

    public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
           KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => ['translateException'],
        ];
    }

    public function translateException(ExceptionEvent $event): void
    {
        $currentException = $event->getThrowable();
        $currentMessage = $currentException->getMessage();

        $translatedMessage = $this->translator->trans($currentMessage);
        $exceptionClass = get_class($currentException);
        $translatedException = new $exceptionClass($translatedMessage);

        $event->setThrowable($translatedException);
    }
}
```

With that, every not-catched Exception will be translated, then converted to an HTTP error response.

Comment: Can this work for our custom exception only ?

Comment: Of course. I guess "custom exception" means those declared within your `src` directory ? In that case, the full name (.i.e namespace + classname) of the exception is `App\...\MyException` . Since the `get_class()` function returns the full name, you may check whether the full name start with "App\". Otherwise you may also make all your custom exceptions implement a custom interface (e.g `TranslatableExceptionInterface`) and use `if ($exception instanceof TranslatableExceptionInterface) { //translate} `.